# Let F and G be orthogonal reflections in two different planes through the origin. Show that FG and GF are rotations about the line of intersection

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to answer the following:

> Let $F$ and $G$ be orthogonal reflections in two different planes through the
> origin in three-space. Show that $FG$ and $GF$ are rotations about the line of
> intersection between the planes. What are the angles of rotation?

Of course, since the determinant of a orthogonal reflection is $-1$, we require that $\det{FG}=\det{GF}=\det{F}\det{G}=1$, thus $GF$ and $FG$ are rotations. But how can I show that these are rotations about the line of intersection between the planes, and how can I determine the angle of rotation? My course does not cover the reflection matrix, but it does cover the rotation matrix.

I tried an approach to let $F=2P'-1$ and $G=2P''-1$ and then try to use the fact that they have to be symmetric to obtain something useful, but I didn't get far before giving up.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any vector of this line of intersection is fixed by $F$ and $G$, hence by $FG$ and $GF.$ This completes your answer to the 1st question. Hint for the angle: restrict to the plane orthogonal to this line...

Comment: Reflecting a point about a plane can be viewed as a rotation about any point on the plane.  The rotation axis has to belong to the plane about the reflection is performed.  Therefore, for the double reflection to be viewed as a rotation, the axis has to belong to the first and second planes, thus it is along their intersection.  Viewing the reflections from a point looking down the intersection line, the rotation angle is equal to twice the angle between the two planes.